# whats the difference between from package import obj as something vs import package as something in python?

Tags: python

stupid question here: I got these two statments in python. First one says go pandas_datareader and make a pdr object of data.

Second line says make a pdr obj as a pandas_datareader.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

What is the difference between them? If I look at the pdr's list of avaliable functions it is definitely different, but aren't they both from pandas_datareader?

thanks

Comment: In one `data` will be `pdr` and in the other `pandas_datareader` will be `pdr`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `import pandas_datareader as pdr` you are importing the `pandas-datareader` package and giving it the `pdr` alias.

But, when you do `from pandas_datareader import data as pdr`, you are importing [*`data` module*](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/data.py) from the `pandas_pandas_datareader` package and giving it the `pdr` alias.

You are essentially importing two different things.